# GC and shuffle read is high (red) in databricks cluster, how to tune this?

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-analysis, databricks

I need recommendation for cluster design in databricks, we have a ETL batch load running every 20 minutes.

- there are 25+ notebooks doing straight merge in silver layer tables( fact/dimensions)
- cluster config  are as follows:

  - instance type- F64- compute optimised
  - worker nodes -3  - 128 gb memroy  X 64 cores
  - driver node - 1 memory optimized - 64 GB  X8 cores

we need to run minimize execution time and increase parallelism

I am attaching snapshot from SPARKUI of databricks cluster (executor page) for your refrence.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMFyf.png

I see red flag for GC time and shuffle read, GC time turns out more than 10% of total task time.
How can we bring this down and we missing our SLA for load cycle.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing the executors and nodes and also giving more memory per executor. Also, you can see which line in your code is specifically taking long by looking at logs.

You need to ensure that you are not performing actions that involve a lot of data shuffling.